# Macbook pro touch bar spoiled with kernel panics

Tags: macbook-pro, kernel-panic, kernel, touch-bar

After dropping my macbook pro, my touch bar has stopped working and I am getting frequent kernel panics

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this or which part of the macbook is faulty?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) I've added an answer but it would be good to know whether your MBP is on/running at the time when you dropped it? Also, can you shed more light on the details (i.e. dropping it on a bed is different to dropping it on hard wooden floors, etc). Finally, are there any signs of physical damage and, if so, where?

Answer (score 1):

Since you've dropped it the first thing you should do is run some hardware diagnostics.

**Run Apple Diagnostics**

Follow the steps below to run Apple Diagnostics:

1. Fully shut down your MBP
2. Restart your MBP
3. Immediately press the <kbd>D</kbd> key and **keep it down** until you see the Diagnostics screen appear
4. Wait for Diagnostics to finish (this typically only takes a few minutes)
5. Once complete, one of two things will appear on the screen:

   - a *No issues found* message
   - a brief description of any errors found plus further instructions
6. If the diagnostics test does find errors, take a note of what they are

**Note:** If pressing and holding the <kbd>D</kbd> key at Step 3 doesn't work, start again at Step 1 and, at Step 3 press and hold both the <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> keys instead. This will try and run diagnostics from the internet instead, so you will need to allow more time for it to complete.

Regardless, take a note of what happens and let me know how you went.

Comment: Also if you're using a firmware password, turn it off: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202731